# Update of another Field based on selection of first two field is not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Have a Look at below code snippet and help me solve the issue. Date1 is filled using JQuery DatePicker. As per Term selection value, Date2 will change.

Also Find the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyumnaswain/myjjLpz8/)

**ISSUES**

1. When i select 4, 6, 12 it's working fine. But after that if i again select 4 or 6 it's not working.
2. Also after selection of Date1 and Term, if i change Date1 again, date2 is not updating.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date1').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0
            
    });
   $('#term').change(function(){
       var date2=$('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
       var term=$('#term').val();
       switch(term){
           case 'T':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 4,date2.getDate());
                break;
           case 'H':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 6,date2.getDate());
                break;
           case 'Y':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 12,date2.getDate());
                break;
            default: 
               alert('Please Select an Interval');  
       }
           $('#date2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
           $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
    });
    $('#date2').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
    $("#date2").prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Date1:<input type="text" id="date1"/>
Interval:<select id="term">
<option>-Select-</option>
   <option value="T">Four Month</option>
   <option value="H">Six Month</option>
   <option value="Y">Twelve Month</option>
</select><br/><br/>
Date2:<input type="text" id="date2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);. It works like a charm.

Updated Code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date1').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0
            
    });
   $('#term').change(function(){
       var date2=$('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
       var term=$('#term').val();
       switch(term){
           case 'T':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 4,date2.getDate());
                break;
           case 'H':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 6,date2.getDate());
                break;
           case 'Y':
                date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 12,date2.getDate());
                break;
            default: 
               alert('Please Select an Interval');  
       }
           $('#date2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            
    });
    $('#date2').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
    $("#date2").prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Date1:<input type="text" id="date1"/>
Interval:<select id="term">
<option>-Select-</option>
   <option value="T">Four Month</option>
   <option value="H">Six Month</option>
   <option value="Y">Twelve Month</option>
</select><br/><br/>
Date2:<input type="text" id="date2"/>
```